# Is it possible to change the time increments in the Date/Time field?

Tags: datetime, fieldtypes

We have a date/time field shown to render the time for a series of workshops but right now Craft only increments in 30 minutes.

Is there a way for us to render 15 minute increments?

Comment: just a note to say that this is now in the 2.2 release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently, but it should probably be a setting on the field.

Craft currently uses [jquery.timepicker](https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) (in `craft/app/resources/lib/jquery.timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js`) and is just going with it's default `step: 30`.

I'll add it to “The List”™.

Comment: does Whisky help said list?

Comment: Whiskey helps everything.  I put it on the 2.2 list and we'll see if we can squeeze it in.

Answer (score 2):

I needed a 10 minute increment. From the CP side, you can just ignore the dropdown and type in the minutes to override. From frontend forms this is not an issue because you can do whoever you want with your own jquery.

Comment: Very good point to mention that you can always ignore the dropdown. I'd go crazy scrolling through 24*4 (or even 24*6) elements.